# Include css style on printing div

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Help on jquery (rookie).
I have this code to print a div and i want to include CSS on it, how to do that?

```
<script language="javascript">
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

Comment: but it isn't jquery, is pure javascript.

Comment: By *include CSS on it* you mean to apply *CSS* to `<div>` ? then you can use inline *CSS* viz best for printing media or you can use *media-query* for print as `@media print {
  div { background: #f00; color: #FFF;}
}`

Comment: changed for javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values on style property. For example:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
         document.getElementById(divName).style.color = 'red';
         var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;            

         document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

         window.print();

         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
```

Your div content will be red.

Comment: and if i want to include 3 classes?

Comment: so you can use `document.getElementById(divName).className = 'firstClass secondClass thirdClass';`

Answer (score 1):

got it:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
         document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>' );
         var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;            

         document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

         window.print();

         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't answer your own question.